# How to make active navigation bar in php?

Tags: php, navigation

Hello I'm trying to make my navigation bar active in php, so that user can know in which page they are on. I'm new to php and don't know much about it. So how can I add a class="active" in this code to make a active nav bar and display all the page in same index.php page.

```
 <a href="?page=home"> Home</a></br>
<a href="?page=news"> News</a></br>
<a href="?page=about"> About</a></br>
<a href="?page=contact"> Contact</a></br>

 <?php
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    include "home.php";
} else {
switch ($_GET['page']) {
    case "home":
         include "home.php";
    break;
    case "news":
         include "news.php";
    break;
    case "about":
         include "about.php";
    break;
    case "contact":
         include "contact.php";
    break;
    default:
         include "home.php";
    };
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of menu items and then use a `foreach` loop to generate the menu dynamically.

That way when you add new items to the array they will show up in the menu:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website</title>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .active {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php

// This is your menu
$items = array("home", "news", "about", "contact");

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $item)
    {
        echo '<a href="?page=' . $item . '" class="active"> ' . $item . '</a></br>';
        $activePage = $item . ".php";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="?page=' . $item . '"> ' . $item . '</a></br>';
    }
}

// Include your page
if (isset($activePage))
{
    include $activePage;   
}
else
{
    include "home.php";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

You should replace all of your code with this code and give it a spin. Using loops to reduce the amount of redundant markup you need to write is not only [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) but will save you a lot of time in the future!

Comment: @sn0w Well that's a little embarrassing. I edited the above ad added some HTML structure to put it into context

Comment: I got a second error page, if I clicked on same link twice its says page not found. Let say if I clicked on news first it shows a news page but if I click it again it says page not found.

Comment: @sn0w The ?page= was left out of the active operation. I edited the code and that should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP code below as navigation. I recommend that you use unordered list (i.e. `<ul><li><a href=""></a></li></ul>`) tags for navigation:

```
<ul>
    <li<?php if($_GET['page']=="home")   { echo " class=\"active\""; } ?>><a href="?page=home"> Home</a></li>
    <li<?php if($_GET['page']=="news")   { echo " class=\"active\""; } ?>><a href="?page=news"> News</a></li>
    <li<?php if($_GET['page']=="about")  { echo " class=\"active\""; } ?>><a href="?page=about"> About</a></li>
    <li<?php if($_GET['page']=="contact"){ echo " class=\"active\""; } ?>><a href="?page=contact"> Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then add the below style to CSS:

```
.active {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    <section id="section1">
        <h2>London1</h2>
        <p>
            London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
        with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
        </p>
        <p>
            Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
            its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
        </p>
    </section>


    <section id="section2" style="display:none">
        <h2>London2</h2>
        <p>
            London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
        with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
        </p>
        <p>
            Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
            its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
        </p>
    </section>


    <section id="section3" style="display:none">
        <h2>London3</h2>
        <p>
            London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
        with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
        </p>
        <p>
            Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
            its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
        </p>
    </section>
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#1").click(function(){
            $("#section1").show();
            $("#section2").hide();
            $("#section3").hide();
        });

        $("#2").click(function(){
            $("#section1").hide();
            $("#section2").show();
            $("#section3").hide();
        });

        $("#3").click(function(){
            $("#section1").hide();
            $("#section2").hide();
            $("#section3").show();
        });
    })



    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar">

    <?php // var_dump($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);  ?>  <!-- this will show your url -->
    <a class="default-link-style <?php if($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]=='/your-path-here-uncomment-var_dump-to-get-it/index.php'){echo 'style-active';}?>"  href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a class="default-link-style <?php if($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]=='/your-path-here-uncomment-var_dump-to-get-it/new-page-here.php'){echo 'style-active';}?>" href="new-page-here.php">New Page Here</a>
    <a class="default-link-style <?php if($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]=='/your-path-here-uncomment-var_dump-to-get-it/next.php'){echo 'style-active';}?>" href="next.php">Next</a>

</nav>

<style>

    .style-active {
            text-decoration: red underline overline wavy;
    }

<style>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-ca">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./mycss.css" type="text/css">
    <title>HOME (page 1/5)</title>
    <!--
    This is an HTML page with four major subdivisions: header, nav, main,     
footer.
    The navigation subdivision is the focus of this example.
    The site, including the nav menu, would be styled using CSS in the 
external stylesheet.
    -->
</head>
<body id="home">  <!-- id indicates page; is used by menu CSS to indicate 
 active page.  No JS needed. -->

<div class="outer">
   <header>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x115/" alt="MyCompany Logo" 
width="450" height="115">
        <h1>My Home Maintenance Co.</h1>
        <figcaption>
            <p>No home repair job in the Valley area is too big for us.    
</p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
        <li class="aboutus"><a href="aboutus.html">about us</a></li>
        <li class="services"><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
        <li class="projects"><a href="projects.html">projects</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
    <div></div>  <!-- Use whatever tags are appropriate for content. -->
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div></div>  <!-- Use whatever tags are appropriate for content. -->
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code does not differ from the question's code and does not contribute to an answer.

Comment: I change it, try with this.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="nav">
    <button id="1">London1</button><br>
    <button id="2">2</button><br>
    <button id="3">3</button><br>
</div>
```

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="index.php">paris1</a><br>
    <a href="paris.php">pzris2</a><br>
    <a href="tokyo.php">paris3</a><br>
</div>
```

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'nav1.php'; ?>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```