# How to add an active class to navigation in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to set 'active' classes onto the list nav elements on click. However, the `add/removeclass` runs before the new page is loaded, thereby setting the `active` class back to the `index.php` list element. Isn't the `document.ready` function supposed to run after the document has finished loading?

Clarifications: All the php files using the same "navbar" elements. The php files are in the same directory level.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $(".nav > li").click(function() {  
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you explain how you are loading the navbar? Is this via `include navbar.php`? Perhaps you could provide code showing the structure of those includes. Generally, if you `include` the navbar in each of the (three) pages, it won't know which one it's on and just set the index.php to `active`, as you told it to. So your jQuery is executed, but immediately after that, you load a new page with the navbar, which has the `active` on the first item.

Comment: Oliver, yes that is exactly how I am doing the navbar `include navbar.php` So how would you recommend I code the navbar to be so it can be across all the different pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make active navigation bar in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749793/how-to-make-active-navigation-bar-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a state-variable on each page containing the pagename, and use that in your navbar to figure out which page is active. Consider the following structure:

In index.php:

```
<?php
$pageName = 'index'; 
// rest of template
```

In navbar.php:

```
<?php
$menuItems = ['index', '1', '2'];
?>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php foreach ($menuItems as $item): ?>
          <li class="<?= $pageName == $item ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="<?= $item ?>"><?= $item ?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you use the `include` directive, all variables in an included file will share the scope of the file they are included in. That way, your navbar can access the `$pageName` variable defined in each of the separate pages.

It might miake sense to use a more sophisticated datastructure for the menu-items than just strings, so that you can have a different value for the `href` and the link-text.

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see which scripts and when are loaded, since there is no php file in the question, the one is resetting active links,

Moreover document.ready does not guarantees that all resources are loaded, it is only meaning that the html document is loaded in order to wait for all content use `onload`

However your on click function will always be working if you attach it to the document, see snippet, you can inspect and see that it is working fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $(document).on('click',".nav > li",function() {  
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.php">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
```